# Simple OpenLayers function not working within jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers

I want to change the visibility (and some other things) of OpenLayers layers via buttons. When I call anyLayer.setVisibility("true") on the button click event via jQuery it is working:

```
$("#anyLayer_button").click(function(){
    anyLayer.setVisibility("true");
}
```

But when I want to do so for many layers using a superior jQuery function and thus calling the Ol layer with a variable firebug tells me "anyLayer.setVisibility is not a function".

```
function superiorFunction(anylayer) {
    $("#" + anyLayer + "_button").click(function(){
        anyLayer.setVisibility("true");
        otherFunction1(anyLayer);
        otherFunction2(anyLayer);
    });
}
```

The other (jQuery) functions are working within the function without any problems.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: Is `anyLayer` visible in the code with the "superior" function?

Comment: the layer is not visible when the site is loaded

Comment: Moreover there is one mistake in your code, you declare `anylayer` but you use `anyLayer`.

Comment: U can see in this link. this problem has been solved. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44612302/change-the-visibility-of-layer-by-using-variable-instead-of-layers-name-itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

Instead of

```
anyLayer.setVisibility("true");
```

i call the layer with the getLayerByName function. It gives an array, from which i choose the first (and single) element:

```
var layerArray = map.getLayersByName(layer);
layerArray[0].setVisibility('true');
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the feeling you are passing the wrong parameter to the second function:

> ```
> function superiorFunction(anylayer) {
>     $("#" + anyLayer + "_button").click(function(){
>         anyLayer.setVisibility("true");
>         otherFunction1(anyLayer);
>         otherFunction2(anyLayer);
>     });
> }
> ```

If the `anylayer` parameter you are passing is a string then `anyLayer.setVisibility("true");` causes error because strings have no `setVisibility()` method...

I think what you really want is a function taking the name of the layer (for constructing the id of the button to register the event) and the layer itself:

```
function superiorFunction(anyLayer_name, anyLayer) {
    $("#" + anyLayer_name + "_button").click(function(){
        anyLayer.setVisibility("true");
        otherFunction1(anyLayer);
        otherFunction2(anyLayer);
    });
}
```

Comment: so, i have to convert the string to anything else?

Comment: You have to use the name of the layer to refer to the id of the button and the layer itself for calling the `setVisibility()` method on it. I updated the answer :)