# Change the visibility of layer by using variable instead of layer's name itself

Tags: javascript, html, gis, openlayers, geoserver

This is my select option.

```
<select id="sel_dist" onChange="seldist();">
    <option value="layer1" selected=selected>None</option>
    <option value="layer2">1</option>
    <option value="layer3">2</option>
</select>
```

This is my layer in Openlayers

```
layer1 =  new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Map",serverWMS,
                                        {layers: 'test:Layer1',transparent: true},
                                        {isBaseLayer:false, visibility: false});
```

What i want to do is when i select option "Layer 1", layer 1 should be visible.

```
function seldist()
{
var layer_name=$("#sel_dist option:selected").val()
layer_name.setVisibility(true);
}
```

But when i use `layer_name.setVisibility`it assumes 'layer_name' as layer name but i want to use it as variable only. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/244408/115

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited:**

```
eval(layer_name).setVisibility(true);
```

Comment: It says "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).setVisibility is not a function
    at seldist"

Comment: Thank you very very much.It worked!! This problem has been bugging me since a long time.